# svg path - three identical waves by setting control points

Tags: svg, path

trying to create smoothly waves (three identical waves)
anchor points are set correctly (`0 25, 240 10, 480 25, 720 10, 960 25, 1200 10, 1440 25`)
problem is params for control points
pls help

```
<svg class='svgup' width="1440" height="25">
<path class='pathup' fill='#007399' d="
M0 0
L0 25
C 0 25 120 10 240 10
C 360 10 500 25 480 25
C 500 25 600 10 720 10
C 840 10 1080 25 960 25
C 1080 25 1080 10 1200 10
C 1320 10 1320 25 1440 25
L 1440 0
L 0 0
z"
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide an image (GIT, JPEG) to illustrate the shape of waves?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Quadratic Bezier:

```html
<svg width="600" height="100">
<path fill='#007399' d="
M 0 0
V 25
Q 100 0 200 25
Q 300 0 400 25
Q 500 0 600 25
V 0
H 0
z"/>
</svg>
```